# Почему загрузка JS файла (скрипта) весом 13,7 мб расходует 3,4 мб трафика?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

Я подключаю скрипт database.js, который весит 13,7 мб. При этом в devtools вкладка сеть показывает, что его загрузка потребовала лишь 3,4 мб трафика. Почему так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего сжимается gzip

Comment: Потому что было сжатие трафика

Comment: Можно проверить сжатие, если нажать на запрос, в разделе `Headers` найти `Response Headers`, и найти `content-encoding`, скорее всего там будет gzip или что-нибудь подобное

Comment: Действительно, gzip